# AWS EC2 Parrot Linux instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, parrot-os

I want to deploy an AWS EC2 instance of [Parrot Linux](https://parrotlinux.org) and I cannot find it in the marketplace.

I have uploaded an OVA to S3 of the latest 4.7 version and tried to import but got an error:

```
ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 5.0-parrot
```

Even when the kernel version is 4.19 (from uname -r command)

Is there a way to get Linux Parrot on AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully imported a Parrot Home 4.7 machine to AWS.
After installing kernel version `4.15.0-65-generic` and removing the stock one the image was imported without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a virtualbox/ virtualmachine image and then convert this to a AMI image.

Here is a write-up on how to do it. http://www.ioncannon.net/system-administration/1246/converting-from-virtualbox-or-vmware-to-ec2-now-easier-than-ever/

If you have been able to bootup your virtualbox, there should not be any issue launching an instance through AMI as well.

Comment: Thanks for the replay, I have installed AWS kernel on my OVA and removed the one that it came with and I'm still getting this error: `ClientError: Unsupported kernel version 4.15.0-1052-aws`